# How to mock a null response from a function delegate in c#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, task, moq

I have a function that I'm passing as a parameter like this:

```
public async Task<Number> MeasureAsync<Number>(Func<Task<Number>> sendFunc)
{
    //implementation
}
```

I want to test this function and test a case where the `sendFunc` returns `null`. In my unit test, I'm attempting to mock the `sendFunc` but I'm getting an error saying my mock is ambiguous. Here is my mock:

```
var functionMock = new Mock<Func<Task<Number>>>();

functionMock.Setup(x => x.Invoke()).ReturnsAsync(null); // error on ReturnsAsync because the call is ambiguous
```

Is there a way I'm supposed to specify the return type?

Comment: I also attempted to do this: ```functionMock.Setup(x=>x.Invoke()).ReturnsAsync<Number>(null);```
but got an error saying ReturnsAsync doesn't exist

Comment: Have you tried `functionMock.Setup(x=>x.Invoke()).Returns(Task.FromResult<Number>(null));`?

Comment: @DannyD: `ReturnAsync<Number>(null)`do not work because it is defined as an extension method with `ReturnAsync<TMock, TResult>...`. See [here](https://github.com/moq/moq4/blob/main/src/Moq/ReturnsExtensions.cs)

Comment: `default(Number)` is typed. `null` is `default(object)`.

Answer (score 0):

looks like I was able to find a solution by specifying the type like so:

```
Number number = null;

functionMock.Setup(x => x.Invoke()).ReturnsAsync(number);
```

Comment: `.ReturnsAsync((Number)null)` should work too.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose from a handful of alternatives

```
functionMock.Setup(x => x.Invoke()).ReturnsAsync((Number)null);
```

```
functionMock.Setup(x => x.Invoke()).ReturnsAsync(default(Number));
```

```
functionMock.Setup(x => x.Invoke()).Returns(Task.FromResult<Number>(null));
```

```
functionMock.Setup(x => x.Invoke().Result).Returns(() => null);
```

and a several combinations of the above ones